# best cloud solution for json request

Tags: java, android, json, amazon-web-services, cloud

I am working on a little  android app that will be requesting json data 3 times a day, this json data will be populated base on data that is fetch from 3 different web sites.

My question is what cloud solution will allow me to used some sort of script/language (python,perl or java) to fetch the data within the cloud itself(make the fetching automatic)  from the these site  and make it available in a json friendly format so my app can fetch it .

One of the AWS services I have been looking at was API gateway but i don't see a way of me fetching the data from within AWS to later make it public as a json API.

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: look into firebase functions

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered running scheduled events on AWS Lambda - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html#supported-event-source-scheduled-events